# HowTo Refresh green outlines of DataAnnotationsValidator after submit

Tags: c#, blazor

how can i remove the green outlines ouf input fields in blazor after submitting the form?
The input modified fields are still green outlined after successful submit.

On my page its possible load another dataset after successful submit.
The new data is loaded correctly into the input fields, but the borders are still green from the inputfields, which were modified in the previous dataset.

I tried it with "StateHasChanged()" at OnValidSubmit of editForm but without success;

Also a button which triggered with onclick "StateHasChanged()" did not help.
Seems to me that "StateHasChanged()" doesnt remove green borders from input fields in blazor.

And a dont want to reload the whole blazor bage with "navigateTo" or something like that.

Comment: What kind of inputs are you using? Any library? Please be more clear and share some code if possible

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to the community! Normally it's a best practice to post a minimal reproducible example for the community to work with, so please do so if you can. I'll make some assumptions because I think I know what's happening and you can make sense out of this. If it's what I think it is, the EditContext for the form needs to be refreshed after you submit a valid form.

Say you have a model property for your form:

```cs
public FormModel Model { get; set; }
```

There are 2 ways that you can attach the model to the `<Editform ... >` Component. One uses the `Model` parameter, and the other uses the `EditContext` parameter. We'll use the latter is it gives us control over the context in our code block.

So your razor file will start to look like this:

```cs
<EditForm EditContext="Context" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" >

    ..... form body and submit button
</EditForm>

@code {

    public FormModel Model { get; set; } = new FormModel();

    public EditContext Context { get; set; }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        //Whatever needs to be done on valid submit

        // Refresh the Editcontext
        Context = new EditContext(Model);

        // You may or may not need this call
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Other initialization code, set your initial form model, etc. 

        // Set the form edit context with your model. 
        Context = new EditContext(Model);
    }
}
```

We set the EditContext during initialization to the model you want to use for your form, and everything should work as normal. The validation outline is driving from the EditContext, so if you supply a new edit context on valid form submit the outline will be gone.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your HandleValidSubmit method should be like this:

```
private void HandleValidSubmit()
{
      EditContext.MarkAsUnmodified();
}
```

Hope this works...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you enet and Nik,
the combination of both your answers made it work.

First i had to bind the EditContext of the EditForm to the "Context" property as Nik wrote.
After valid submit i call the "MarkAsUnmodified" as enet wrote.:

`<EditForm EditContext="Context" OnValidSubmit="@MyInsertMethodAsync">`

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Context = new EditContext(MyViewModel);
    await MyViewModel.InitializePropertiesAsync();
}

private async Task MyInsertMethodAsync()
{
    await MyViewModel.InsertMyStuffAsync();
    Context.MarkAsUnmodified();
}
```

Comment: no, first you've got to create a Blazor project... ;)You've got an answer telling you do this: EditContext.MarkAsUnmodified(); This line of code do the trick.  The answer is not that you should create an EditContext object. This is self-evident as much as the need to create a project to run this code, etc. Note: There is a way to express how useful is an answer: It can be accepted by clicking on the check icon (turning it green) as well as upvoting the answer (clicking the up-arrow)